# How can I add extra audio streamS codecs to my files before they get uploaded

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add extra audio streams to my files with both 7.1, 5.1 and 2.0 respectively (aac, ac3, eac3, truehd, dts to aac, ac3, eac3, truehd, dts). How do I go about doing this? I have tried using both tdarr and unmanic, but I don't know what I'm doing.  I want take whatever audio the files come with and duplicate it/add extra audio streams with different audio codecs such as aac, ac3, eac3, truehd, dts as well different audio channels such as 7.1, 5.1 and 2.0 respectively, although I am not sure if 5.1 to 7.1 is possible or even necessary.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474/

Comment: i read thought link and didn't see anything specifically for what i want to do

Comment: See the "Add audio" example.

Comment: according to that diagram it is using a external audio which is not what I am after, i need to take whatever audio the files comes with and convert/clone it to "eac3, truehd, dts to aac, ac3, eac3, truehd, dts" 7.1 or 5.1/2.0 respectively.

Comment: It was unclear what you wanted so I assumed that you already had audio that you wanted to add.

Comment: i need something that take whatever codec the file comes with and clone it/ add extra streams into aac, ac3, eac3 7.1 or 5.1/2.0 respectively

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to take the input audio and transcode it to multiple different lossy audio streams. If so, you want the `-map` command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mka -map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 480k -map 0:a:0 -c:a:1 ac3 -b:a:1 640k -map 0:a:0 -c:a:2 eac3 -b:a:2 448k out.mka
```

etc. That should give you a general idea. See [map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) as well as [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Audio-Decoders) for info on audio codecs and channel mappings. Note that ffmpeg's DTS encoder is considered **experimental**.

Comment: thank you very much, i will give this a try thanks, do u know how i could automate this on cloud (ded/vps) with either tdarr, unmanic or a script that runs and move the files to a "complete folder"  before the files gets uploaded, i know this is outside the scope of my question but if know and have the knowledge and want to share and help me please feel free, thank you.

Comment: @AnielArias Should be asked as a new question. Super User is not a forum format, but a Q&A format where each page is an individual question.

Comment: @AnielArias if the answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: understood and done